# I need to generate a table dynamically using jquery which will show the form data entered by user

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        #basicTable {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

            #basicTable td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
    </style>
   
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            createTable();
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                debugger;
                
                addRow();
                $("#basicTable").on('click', '.rem', function () {
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });
                $("#btnedit").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
                    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
                    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
                    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
                    $("#txt1").val(" ");
                    $("#txt1").focus();
                    $("#txt2").val(" ");
                    $("#txt3").val(" ");
                    
                    //$("#txt1").focus();
                });
            });
        });
        function createTable() {
            debugger;
            var table = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
            $('<td></td>').text("Name").appendTo(row);
            $('<td></td>').text("E-mail").appendTo(row);
            $('<td></td>').text("Phone").appendTo(row);
            table.appendTo($('#container'));
        }
        function addRow() {
            debugger;
            var table = $('#basicTable');
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
            $('<td></td>').text($('#txt1').val()).appendTo(row);
            $('<td></td>').text($('#txt2').val()).appendTo(row);
            $('<td></td>').text($('#txt3').val()).appendTo(row);
            $('<td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" /></td>').appendTo(row);
            $('<td><input type="button" id="btndel" value="Delete" class="rem" /></td>').appendTo(row);
            $("#form").trigger('reset');
        
            return table;
        }
        //    var table = document.createElement('table');
        //    for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
        //        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        //        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        //        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        //        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        //        var text1 = document.createTextNode('Name');
        //        var text2 = document.createTextNode('E-mail');
        //        var text3 = document.createTextNode('Phone')
        //        td1.appendChild(text1);
        //        td2.appendChild(text2);
        //        td3.appendChild(text3);
        //        tr.appendChild(td1);
        //        tr.appendChild(td2);
        //        tr.appendChild(td3);

        //        table.appendChild(tr);
        //    }
        //    document.body.appendChild(table);
        //});

        //});



        // Your code goes here.

    </script>






    <form id="form">
        <fieldset style="display:inline">
            <label for="Name" id="lab">Name:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" /><br /><br />
            <label for="E-mail" id="lab1">E-mail:</label><input type="email" id="txt2" /><br /><br />
            <label for="Phone" id="lab2">Ph.No.:</label><input type="tel" id="txt3" /><br /><br />
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="submit" />
        </fieldset>
        
        <div id="container" style="position:relative;margin:34px;">
        
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The code below which i'm using is not printing even the table.I want that when user fills the form fields and click the submit button both table and row will be visible and it will contain the three input fields entered by user and additionally it'll place two buttons as edit and delete on two extra coloumns!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#lab").append("&nbsp;", "&nbsp;");
            $("#lab1").append(" ");
            $("#lab2").append(" ");
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var table = document.createElement('table');
                for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

                    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                    var text1 = document.createTextNode('Name');
                    var text2 = document.createTextNode('E-mail');
                    var text3 = document.createTextNode('Phone')
                    td1.appendChild(text1);
                    td2.appendChild(text2);
                    td3.appendChild(text3);
                    tr.appendChild(td1);
                    tr.appendChild(td2);
                    tr.appendChild(td3);

                    table.appendChild(tr);
                }
                document.body.appendChild(table);
            });
              
            });

        

    

    </script>
    <form>
        <fieldset style="display:inline">
            <label for="Name" id="lab">Name:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" /><br /><br />
            <label for="E-mail" id="lab1">E-mail:</label><input type="email" id="txt2" /><br /><br />
            <label for="Phone" id="lab2">Ph.No.:</label><input type="tel" id="txt3" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you try out knockoutJS. It is very simple to do this.

Comment: in submit button add a click event and define that function instead of using  `document.ready`

Comment: i need to place two dynamically added buttons as edit and delete to the column when user submits the form,so that it will allow him/her to update the data and delete if required

Answer (score 0):

Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/2krdupvc/

You could also change `$(document).ready(function () {}` to `.load` just to make sure everything is loaded (not only the DOM) before launching your actions.

Make sure that Jquery is loaded and you don't have errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is that you are creating text node with the values as `Name`, `Email` and `Phone`. Instead, if you want to populate it with actual values, then you can simply use jquery `val()` function from input attributes.
Try the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cujdknuo/

(I have changed form to div because of issues with fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

## Updated.

Try this.callEditPage() and callDeletePage() is just for testing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#btn").click(function () {
                     var table = document.createElement('table');
                     table.border = "1";
                     var values = new Array();
                     values.push(["Name", "E-mail", "Phone No.","Edit","Delete"]);
                     var name = $('#txt1').val();
                     var email = $('#txt2').val();
                     var phone = $('#txt3').val();
                     var editBtn = "<button type='button' onclick=\"callEditPage()\">Edit</button>";
                     var delBtn = "<button type='button' onclick=\"callDeletePage()\">Delete</button>";
                     values.push([name, email, phone,editBtn,delBtn]);
                    
                     var columnCount = values[0].length;
                     var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                     for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                         var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                         headerCell.innerHTML = values[0][i];
                         row.appendChild(headerCell);
                     }
                     for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                         row = table.insertRow(-1);
                         for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                             var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                             cell.innerHTML = values[i][j];
                         }
                     }
                     var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
                     dvTable.innerHTML = "";
                     dvTable.appendChild(table);
             return false;
                 });
             
             });
         function callEditPage()
         {
             alert("Your Are Inside Edit");
         }
         function callDeletePage() {
             alert("Your Have Deleted");
         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div>
            <fieldset style="display:inline">
                <label for="Name" id="lab">Name:</label><input type="text" id="txt1" /><br /><br />
                <label for="E-mail" id="lab1">E-mail:</label><input type="email" id="txt2" /><br /><br />
                <label for="Phone" id="lab2">Ph.No.:</label><input type="tel" id="txt3" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit" />
            </fieldset>
       <div id="dvTable">    
    </div>
    </div>
     
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but your answer's still incomplete,i want two more columns to be added dynamically to the table which will be two buttons for editing and Deleting the row and if the user clicks edit it'll redirect him/her to the form where he/she can update the fields.

Comment: @Kamal Singh Try updated one and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: Instead of deleting/editing the concerned row your code is just showing an alert message.But your design is correct without functionality!

Comment: @Kamal .. alert message is just for an example.What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have already written the code to delete the concerned row,it's just like i'm  on the final step of my task to let the user edit the concerned row by putting those values in form!

Comment: Great. happy coding. :)